# Segfault when accessing char[]

Tags: android, c, segmentation-fault, realpath, bionic

I've got a function

```
int foo() {
    ...
    char* real_path_buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*PATH_MAX);
    realpath("a/certain/path/that/doesnt/exist", real_path_buffer);
    ...
}
```

That makes a call to `realpath` in Android bionic

```
char* realpath(const __restrict char*, __restrict char*){
    char path1[PATH_MAX], path2[PATH_MAX], path3[PATH_MAX];
    ...
    path1 = something_valid; //recall, this is a library function
    ...
    memcpy(path2, path1, a_valid_size);
    ...
}
```

And when passing a certain non-existent path to `realpath` from a production like scenario, I get a segfault upon accessing`path2` in any way (it happens when I simply try to print it as well as `memcpy` to it).

I have verified that the program is not out of memory when the segfault occurs (by making a call to malloc and verifying that its return is not `NULL`) but you can be assured that this call happens on a fairly hefty stack.

I've also verified that in less intense code paths, `realpath` accurately returns `NULL` without segfaulting.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What is the value of PATH_MAX?

Comment: A large number defined in <linux/limits.h>

Comment: Yes, well the point is that you need to know what that number is, in order to evaluate whether 3 arrays of that size on the stack will cause a stack overflow. Of course, you also need to know how big the stack is, and how deep you are into the stack when you call `realpath`.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. How can I determine those things (the size of the stack I'm working with and my current depth in the stack)?

Comment: The stack size is a large number defined in the Android documentation. You can find the  (approximate) current depth by taking the address of a local variable in the top-level function (saved as a global variable), and subtracting the address of a local variable in some lower-level function. Note that both addresses need to be cast as `char *` to get the stack depth in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to completely verify this but I believe it was a stack overflow.

Comment: If the original problem is repeatable, one would think you could test that via similar sized stack allocations, vs. running the same code at a shallower stack depth.